# Wrong UTC inside docker

Tags: c#, docker

I'm currently trying to get my datetimes correct inside a docker but it's something I don't understand.

This is the result I get if I run my C# code locally:

```
[09:10:09 INF] DateTime.UtcNow: 8/25/2021 7:10:09 AM
[09:10:09 INF] DateTime.Now: 8/25/2021 9:10:09 AM
[09:10:09 INF] DateTimeOffset.UtcNow: 8/25/2021 7:10:09 AM +00:00
[09:10:09 INF] DateTimeOffset.Now: 8/25/2021 9:10:09 AM
```

So this match my local time just fine. Then I try to run this code inside a docker and get this:

```
[09:34:16 INF] DateTime.UtcNow: 8/24/2021 9:34:16 AM
[09:34:16 INF] DateTime.Now: 8/24/2021 9:34:16 AM
[09:34:16 INF] DateTimeOffset.UtcNow: 8/24/2021 9:34:16 AM +00:00
[09:34:16 INF] DateTimeOffset.Now: 8/24/2021 9:34:16 AM
```

So the utc seems to be wrong and it don't have correct offset in local time so I added a timezone (-e TZ=Europe/Stockholm) and get this:

```
[11:32:59 INF] DateTime.UtcNow: 8/24/2021 9:32:59 AM
[11:32:59 INF] DateTime.Now: 8/24/2021 11:32:59 AM
[11:32:59 INF] DateTimeOffset.UtcNow: 8/24/2021 9:32:59 AM +00:00
[11:32:59 INF] DateTimeOffset.Now: 8/24/2021 11:32:59 AM
```

A bit better (the offset is correct) but UTC is still off with two hours. So what am I missing? Feels like UTC in docker is always my local time.

Edit:

Here is my docker file (it copy a couple off dll:s and then execute a python-script that call `dotnet test`)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.203-focal

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus && apt-get install -y python3

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./src/Test/bin/Debug/net5.0/ .
COPY ./Tools/docker.py .

# run tests on docker run
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "docker.py"]
```

The python file do a couple of thing but mostly it just execute a dotnet test command:

```
bashCmd = ["dotnet", "test", "test.dll", "--results-directory", "TestResult", "--filter",
               "Name=DateTest", "--verbosity", verbosity, "--logger", "trx"]

process = subprocess.run(bashCmd)
```

And the test I run is just a simple .NET 5 test in NUnit:

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class MyDateTest
    {
        [TestCase(TestName = "DateTest")]
        public void DateTest()
        {
            Log.Information($"DateTime.UtcNow: {DateTime.UtcNow}");
            Log.Information($"DateTime.Now: {DateTime.Now}");
            Log.Information($"DateTimeOffset.UtcNow: {DateTimeOffset.UtcNow}");
            Log.Information($"DateTimeOffset.Now: {DateTime.Now}");
            Assert.Fail("meh");
        }
    }
```

I'm currently running windows 10.

Comment: I can't reproduce your symptoms. I works as it should on my machine (Windows 10 host with WSL2 and an image based on mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0. Please add more information to your post to let us reproduce your scenario (at least the Dockerfile).

Comment: What operating systems are you running on the host and on the container? Could it be due to Windows expecting the system clock to be in local time, and linux expecting it to be in UTC?

Comment: Hey, I have added some more information about my docker file and which OS I'm using.  Yeah feels like it can be some missmatch between the local clock and the docker clock.

Comment: What version of Docker are you running?

Comment: Engine version 20.10.7 and api version 1.41

Comment: To see if this is related to docker or Windows, it would be interesting to see what a Linux distro running under WSL reports. Do you have any installed? If not, then you could run `wsl --install -d Ubuntu`. When the installation has finished and you're at the Ubuntu prompt, type `date` and `cat /etc/timezone` and see what it says.

Comment: I just tried it and `date` said `Tue Aug 24 15:45:06 CEST 2021` (my local windows 10 time is 13:24) and `cat /etc/timezone` gave me `Europe/Stockholm` so it feels a bit weird. Both wrong date and time somehow.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4526